# Google Analytics - Source of First Session for Repeat Users

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Using Google Analytics and trying to figure out the source for the first session of users who recorded 5 or more sessions over a time period. Basically want to figure out how they originally found the site.

Answer (score 1):

Make a segment with your conditions. And just check channel or source/medium of the segment.